# Finding the dimension of the intersection of two real algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, real-algebraic-geometry, hausdorff-measure

Suppose we have two polynomials $p, q \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and we are interested in their simultaneous zeros. Parameter counting tells us that the zero set most probably is going to be a one dimensional curve. But how can I make this statement rigourous? Is there any theorem which gives you the Hausdorff dimension of such a zero set? Indeed, we will have to assume that $p$ and $q$ have no common factors.

Comment: What exactly is a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Do you mean in $\mathbb{R} [x_1, x_2, x_3]$?

Comment: because you work over the reals, parameter counting will tell you nothing.

Comment: For a postive integer  $n$ denote by $P_n$ the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$ in three variables. Sard's theorem shows that if $n$ is sufficiently  large, there exists a measure zero  subset $Z\subset  P_n\times P_n$ such that for $(p,q)\in P_n\times P_n\setminus Z$ the  set $\{p=q=0\}$ has dimension $1$ if nonempty. In fact $Z$ itself is semialgebraic.

Answer (score 3):

As in my comment denote by $P_n$ the subspace of $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\bR[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ consisting of polynomials of degree $\leq n$.  Consider the map

$$  F: \bR^3\times P_n\times P_n\to\bR^2,\;\;(x,p,q)\mapsto  (p(x),q(x)).$$

If $n$ is sufficiently large, then  for any $x\in\bR^3$  the map

$$ P_n\times P_n\ni (p,q)\mapsto (p(x),q(x))\in\bR^2  $$

is a submersion. We deduce that the set

$$\Lambda=\{(x,p,q)\in\bR^3\times P_n\times P_n;\;\;p(x)=q(x)=0\} $$

is a submanifold  of codimension $2$.  We have a natural map

$$\pi:\Lambda\times P_n\times P_n\to  P_n\times P_n,\;\;(x,p,q)\mapsto(p,q).  $$

Sard's theorem shows that most $(p,q)\in P_n\times P_n$ is a regular value of $\pi$. The fibers of $\pi$ will generically have dimension $1$. Note that the fiber of $\pi$ over $(p,q)$ is the set $\{p=q=0\}$.